# I can't fine-tune clip model from huggingface

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, clip

Clip is a very powerful cool thing. It makes it easy to classify images. But when you have to sort real people, or let's say anime characters by their names, it gets more and more difficult because the model, I understand, is not trained for that purpose. I'd like to teach the neural network to distinguish between a few anime characters by their names.
To do that, I wrote the following code:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
import os
from PIL import Image
from datasets import Dataset
from transformers import CLIPProcessor, CLIPModel, CLIPConfig, CLIPImageProcessor
from torchvision.transforms import Compose, Resize, CenterCrop, ToTensor, Normalize
import torch
from transformers import TrainingArguments, image_processing_utils, default_data_collator
from transformers import Trainer

model_name_or_path = 'openai/clip-vit-base-patch32'
dataset_path = "dataset224"
max_target_length=32

config = CLIPConfig.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path)
model = CLIPModel(config).to("cuda")
processor = CLIPProcessor.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path)
image_processor = CLIPImageProcessor.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path)

dataset = load_dataset(dataset_path)

def collate_fn(batch):
    def toinp(text):
        input_ids = processor.tokenizer(text,
                                padding="max_length",
                                max_length=max_target_length,
                                truncation=True).input_ids
        return input_ids

    def topix(img):
        image_transforms = Compose([
            #Resize(config.vision_config.image_size), #no need because images are already 224x224
            #CenterCrop(config.vision_config.image_size),
            ToTensor(),
            Normalize(mean=image_processor.image_mean, std=image_processor.image_std)
        ])
        image = img.convert('RGB')
        pixel_values = processor.feature_extractor(image, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values
        return pixel_values.squeeze()

    return {
        'pixel_values': torch.stack([topix(x['image']) for x in batch]),
        'input_ids': torch.tensor([toinp(x['text']) for x in batch]),
        "return_loss": True
    }

training_args = TrainingArguments(
  output_dir="./cilp-banana",
  per_device_train_batch_size=16,
  evaluation_strategy="steps",
  num_train_epochs=1000,
  save_steps=100,
  eval_steps=100,
  logging_steps=10,
  learning_rate=5e-8,
  save_total_limit=40,
  remove_unused_columns=False,
  push_to_hub=False,
  load_best_model_at_end=True,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=dataset['train'],
    eval_dataset=dataset['train'],
    data_collator=collate_fn,
    tokenizer=processor.feature_extractor,
)

train_results = trainer.train()
trainer.save_model()
```

I also compiled a dataset myself:

```
[max@arch clipclip]$ ls -R dataset224
dataset224:
train

dataset224/train:
maru10.png  maru15.png  maru4.png  maru9.png     osage13.png  osage2.png  osage7.png  yuka12.png  yuka2.png  yuka7.png
maru11.png  maru16.png  maru5.png  metadata.csv  osage14.png  osage3.png  osage8.png  yuka13.png  yuka3.png  yuka8.png
maru12.png  maru1.png   maru6.png  osage10.png   osage15.png  osage4.png  osage9.png  yuka15.png  yuka4.png  yuka9.png
maru13.png  maru2.png   maru7.png  osage11.png   osage16.png  osage5.png  yuka10.png  yuka16.png  yuka5.png
maru14.png  maru3.png   maru8.png  osage12.png   osage1.png   osage6.png  yuka11.png  yuka1.png   yuka6.png
```

All images are 224x224, and the metadata.csv file is just a database for a dataset where the key is the name of the character image and the value is just the character name.

It's pretty simple at first glance, but when I train a neural network model, there's a weird glue going on.

So, for starters, when I'm training a model, the validation loss is lower than the training loss. And loss is higher than 2

```
Step    Training Loss   Validation Loss
100     2.715400    2.059683
200     2.629200    2.064471
300     2.563500    2.075815
400     2.470700    2.090488
500     2.427400    2.103193
600     2.335900    2.111736
700     2.307500    2.123242
800     2.275900    2.131021
900     2.237800    2.138617
1000    2.225800    2.147700
1100    2.198000    2.152123
1200    2.210500    2.159419
1300    2.160800    2.162220
1400    2.187700    2.165019
1500    2.162500    2.168924
```

I thought that since the loss is high, then the model shouldn't have been trained normally and when I suggested that she classify the anime character, the similarity rating of the text to the image would be low compared to the simple description. Instead, the model seems to randomly attribute more points to the character names than to the simple description. It happens even with non-anime images.

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
import os

from transformers import CLIPProcessor, CLIPModel

m = "cilp-banan"
url = "land.jpg"

model = CLIPModel.from_pretrained(m).to("cuda")
processor = CLIPProcessor.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-base-patch32")

image = Image.open(url)

inputs = processor(text=["osage", "maru", "yuka", "landscapes with mountains"], images=image, return_tensors="pt", padding=True).to("cuda")

outputs = model(**inputs)
logits_per_image = outputs.logits_per_image # this is the image-text similarity score
probs = logits_per_image.softmax(dim=1) # we can take the softmax to get the label probabilities
print(probs)
```

finetuned clip:
`tensor([[9.6232e-01, 8.5255e-05, 8.2687e-03, 2.9322e-02]], device='cuda:0',grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward0>)`

openai/clip-vit-base-patch32:
`tensor([[1.3411e-02, 3.4453e-03, 1.5550e-04, 9.8299e-01]], device='cuda:0',grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward0>)`

What am I doing wrong? Did I write the code wrong, or did I put together the dataset wrong, or did I do it all at once?

Comment: Can you try a train batch_size of 1?

Comment: Well, I tried to change the per_device_train_batch_size to 1. Now the values don't change at all.  
```
Step  Training Loss  Validation Loss  
100  0.000000  2.083108  
200  0.000000  2.083108  
300  0.000000  2.083108
```

Comment: have you solved this issue? I'm facing the similar problem rn